# 'x' and 'y' lengths differ in Shiny Reactive Plot

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny. I'm working on a Shiny app with a reactive plot. It seems to do well, except when I tried to change the number of days (t) to something less than 365. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the data frame or the way the plot is coded

This is an on-going hobby but Im stuck on this. Note, updated this after Ben's comments to include the ui

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Simulation"),
  sidebarPanel(


    sliderInput(inputId = "cr", label = "Contact Rate", value = 10, min = 0, max = 100),
    sliderInput(inputId = "tp", label = "Tramsmission Probability", value = 0.2, min = 0, max = 1),
    sliderInput(inputId = "ipd", label = "Infectious Period", value = 5, min = 0, max = 50),
    sliderInput(inputId = "lpd", label = "Latent Period", value = 2, min = 0, max = 50),
    sliderInput(inputId = "W", label = "Susceptible Population", value = 100, min = 0, max = 10917089),
    sliderInput(inputId = "X", label = "Intial Number of Infected", value = 100, min = 0, max = 10917089),
    sliderInput(inputId = "Y", label = "Intial Number of Exposed", value = 50, min = 0, max = 10000),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  seir_ode<-function(time,Y,par){
    S<-Y[1]
    E<-Y[2]
    I<-Y[3]
    R<-Y[4]

    beta<-par[1]
    sigma<-par[2]
    gamma<-par[3]

    dYdt<-vector(length=3)
    dYdt[1]=(-beta * S * I)
    dYdt[2]=(beta * S * I) - (sigma * E)
    dYdt[3]=(sigma * E) - (gamma * I)

    return(list(dYdt))
  }


  sol<-reactive({ 
    req(input$cr, input$tp, input$ipd,input$lpd, input$W ,input$X ,input$Y )
    beta<-input$cr * input$tp
    sigma<-1/input$lpd
    gamma<-1/input$ipd
    N <- input$W + input$X + input$Y
    init <- c(input$W/N,input$X/N,input$Y/N)
    par = c(beta,sigma,gamma)
    t = seq(0,100) #problem

    lsoda(init,t,seir_ode,par)

  }) 

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    sols <- as.data.frame(sol())
    with(sols, {
      plot(t,sols[,2],type="l",col="blue",ylim=c(0,1),ylab="Proportion")
      lines(t,sols[,3],col="orange")
      lines(t,sols[,4],col="red")  
      lines(t,1-rowSums(sols[,2:4]),col="green")
    })
    legend(300,0.7,legend=c("S","E","I","R"),col=c("blue","orange","red","green"), lty=1,cex=0.8)

  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you share your `ui` to make this reproducible?

Comment: edited my post, ui included

Comment: `t` does not exist in `sols` in your `renderPlot` - you need to use `time` instead. For example, `plot(time...` and `lines(time...` etc.